# Cannot Deploy Universal App on Microsoft Lumia 950 XL (Visual Studio Community 2015)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, vs-community-edition

I am getting this error when trying to deploy a blank universal application on Microsoft Lumia 950 XL:

**DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988946667**

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015, Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2

I have tried one proposed solution, but did not work:

```
net start IpOverUsbSvc
```

It's worth to note that I can see my device connected using the WinAppDeployCmd utility, and I can install my application manually as well:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86>WinAppDeployCmd.exe devices

Windows App Deployment Tool Version 10.0.0.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Discovering devices... IP Address      GUID                            Model/Name
127.0.0.1       004a0090-8800-1169-0000-000000000000    Lumia 950 XL Dual SIM (RM-1116) 
Done.
```

I have the same exact issue on 2 Windows 7 machines.

Can anyone help please with this issue, I have been stuck for a week now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

On the phone, turn on developer mode and device discovery.
 Reboot the phone. Install the latest update on the phone (there is a fresh one).

On the PC:
cmd WinAppDeployCmd.exe devices
Unplug the usb cable between phone and pc
cmd WinAppDeployCmd.exe devices again (it must show the phone ip address)
Replug the usb cable

Try a deploy from VS again (for ARM).

It worked for me after cursing a lot. These guys are doing harakiri.

Otherwise, pair your device as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#device-discovery-and-pairing
And install the app from the device portal. Sigh. I could as well waste my time with horrid dirty "modern" JavaScript frameworks.