# Unexpected Error: DEP0001 - 1988946667

Tags: debugging, windows-10-universal, lumia

I'm trying debug Windows 10 App and always get "DEP0001 - 1988946667" error.

I'm trying:

- Connect Lumia 950 by USB and debug with "Device" mode in Visual Studio 2015 (I activated developers mode in phone)
- The previous step with ARM architecture
- Debug with Windows 10 emulator.

I'm only can debug like local app in my laptop...

But always I get the same error message...

Any ideas?

**Update: The main problem is the build version of Windows 10. If returns to 1511 all works fine**

Comment: In this MSDN link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9304af75-a544-4c08-9334-f807610878d1/cannot-deploy-uwp-app-to-win10m-14356-dep0001-unexpected-error-2147014836?forum=wpdevelop someone make this comment **This is unfortunately a known issue with the Windows 10 Insider Builds. We hope the issue should be fixed shortly. But in the meanwhile, there is no workaround but to revert back to the RTM build of Windows (10586). It is likely that the issue does not exist in the slow ring either, but we are not sure about that.** 

But I have 14393.82 version...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Deploy Universal App on Microsoft Lumia 950 XL (Visual Studio Community 2015)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751305/cannot-deploy-universal-app-on-microsoft-lumia-950-xl-visual-studio-community-2)

Comment: Problem solved: I check the main problem is the build of Windows 10. I return to build 1511 and all works fine.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, I'd suggest you write an answer by yourself. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the build version of Windows 10. If returns to 1511 all works fine