# UWP app debugging Error DEP:0001; Unexpected Error: -1988946667

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-debugging

I started looking into UWP app developing, and started with a Hello World tutorial.
All is fine, it starts and runs well on Local Machine.
The problem is when I try to Debug on emulator or real device. Then it gives me the following error: "Unexpected Error: DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988946667", and an error window that states: "Verify the project is selected to be deployed in the Solution Configuration Manager, or deploy it explicitly by clicking one of the Deploy commands in the Build menu".

So, I did turn on the Developer mode on the developing computer, the actual device, and on the emulators.
I have enabled the BIOS settings for Hyper-v. The hyper-v is enabled and started.
I have tried the WinAppDeployCmd utility. It works fine and it sees my device.
I have paired my device with the computer, and it is accessible trough the Device Portal.
I have Windows 10 PRO version 1607, Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 with Update 3.

In the Solution Configuration Manager, the check box beneath Deploy is checked.
I am wasting a lot of time with something supposed to work "out of the box". Please help!

PS. I have read Sergio's post: "[Unexpected Error: DEP0001 - 1988946667](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120761/unexpected-error-dep0001-1988946667)", but I don`t understand what build version is him referring to: the SDK version, or the Windows version on the development computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have managed to solve my problem.
I have got my Visual Studio up to date, and then, I started a repair from the Visual Studio setup.
Now I can debug in the Emulators. Hope this will help somebody save the time I`ve lost. :)

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, Andrei Ivanov:), if so, would you please mark it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours. Have a nice day!